# sphinxsearch service fails after upgrade from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, sphinx, ubuntu-14.04

After performing an upgrade on my server from 13.10 to 14.04, I'm now getting the following error when starting up the sphinxsearch process via `service sphinxsearch start`

`FATAL: USE_64BIT inconsistency (binary=1, binlog=0); recovery requires previous binary version`

I've performed searches to try to figure out why this is happening and how to resolve, but haven't found much that helps.  I've seen where people are getting this on windows, but that hasn't done much to help either.

If anyone has any insight into this, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, well, I did a little further digging and found this:

http://linux-aks.blogspot.com/2012/03/fatal-binlog-meta-file.html

Just delete the binlog.meta file and restart the service.  No further error.